# Adding multiple inherited instances of different children types in a TPT Mapping EF4.1

Tags: inheritance, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

**Given the model:**

```
public abstract class Person 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Customer : Person 
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
public class User : Person 
{
    public string Password {get;set;}
}
```

I need to add a **customer** and an **user** that refers to the same person

```
context.Set<Customer>().Add(new Customer { Name = "X" });
context.SaveChanges();
```

Now I have 2 entries in my db

```
Persons
Id: 1

Customers
Id: 1
Name: X
```

When I try to add the **user** to the person 1

```
context.Set<Customer>().Add(new User { Id = 1, Password = "0" });
context.SaveChanges();
```

Entity Framework **ignores** *Id = 1* and create a new person.
How to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I need to add a customer and an user that refers to the same person"

This makes no sense because customer and user do not **refer** to a person, they **are** a person. If you have an object of type `Customer` and another object of type `User` there is no third identity called `Person`. There are only two identities and both have properties inherited from the `Person` base class.

If you have that situation in your domain that a person can be a customer and a user at the same time modeling this with an inheritance hierarchy is not the ideal approach. You should better have a reference in both classes pointing to a person, like so:

```cs
public class Person 
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public Person Person {get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Password {get;set;}
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public Person Person {get;set;}
}
```